# SwiftUI Playground Build Schemes

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

(Xcode 15)

When creating a new SwiftUI playground I am getting a warning that says "Skipping duplicate build file in Compile Sources Build Phase ..." I went to SwiftUI Playground > Edit Schemes and see 2 build targets listed both of which are 'SwiftUI Playground' build targets. One is only there for test and the other has all options selected, including test. Can I remove the target that's there for test only? Is there a way to determine where these came from?

I searched archives and didn't find a direct answer. I am new to Xcode, so haven't tried to remove the target yet, but I suspect it will resolve the problem if I remove it. Just not sure what downstream problems I might create.